# Eclipse neon 3 hot swaping for JSP's not working

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I just updated my eclipse neon 2 to 3 few days ago and since then, every changes happening within JSP  pages not deploying instantly in application, the process which happened in neon 2. since I'm working with spring boot and tomcat, I have to restart the embedded tomcat every time changes happen in JSP's.
What is going to be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you're trying to use a 3 year old version of Eclipse and the Web Tools Platform with a version of Tomcat that, even today, has yet to have a proper release. It should be supported in the current Neon.3 release

Answer (score 0):

Gosh!!!
It had nothing to do with eclipse or anything. just a feature added to spring.
To solve the problem just add the following line to `application.properties`

```
server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.development = true
```